# Why does $\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{-r}{k}p^r(p-1)^k=p^r(1+p-1)^{-r}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

For any positive real number $r$, it is clear that $\binom{-r}{k}(-1)^k\geq0$ for all positive integer $k$. The general binomial theorem then implies

$$\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{-r}{k}p^r(p-1)^k=p^r(1+p-1)^{-r}=1$$

I get the generalisation of $\binom{-r}{k}$, and I have searched through Wikipedia about the Binomial Theorem, it only mentions the generalisation to multinomial theorem and complex numbers.

I don't quite get how do they get $p^r(1+p-1)^{-r}$. It is very appreciated if anyone could explain a bit on it. Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee What part of the link you gave can aid the OP in her/his quest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html) will give you the answer you need. In particular, observe that $p^r$ can be factored out, so you end up with $$p^r\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{-r}{k}(p-1)^k = p^r\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{-r}{k}(p-1)^k(1)^{-r-k} = p^r(1+p-1)^{-r} = 1\text{.}$$